# What Are the Advantages of Static IP Addresses?

Tags: ip, protocol-theory

As there are two types of IP addresses, why static addresses are harder to maintain, and if they are so what is their advantage to have one instead of dynamic IP adresses?

Comment: "_As there are two types of IP addresses_" Yes, there are IPv4 (32-bit) addresses and IPv6 (128-bit) addresses. You could classify each type by other types (unicast, multicast, broadcast, forwardable, global, link-local, etc.).

Comment: Are these questions all homework?

Comment: No, this is not homework, I am studying alone and this site is very helpful cause I have no instructor by my side. @cpt_fink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As there are two types of IP addresses,

I guess you mean two ways of assigning IP addresses - dynamically and statically.

> why static addresses are harder to maintain, and if they are so what is their advantage to have one instead of dynamic IP adresses?

The static address is maintained on the device (node), so changing them requires reconfiguring each node separately. DHCP addresses are maintained on a central DHCP server, so there's only on point for reconfiguration.

A common approach is to use DHCP for centrally assigned addresses but to use reserved addresses, so that all nodes (or just the important ones) permanently keep their IP addresses, effectively like statically assigned ones.